# Change of select should take effect to all other select elements and vice versa

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I created a directive and used it twice on the same page. But they are placed into another directive

```
<directive1>
    <select-directive/>
</directive1>

<directive1>
    <select-directive/>
</directive1>
```

Now changing the value of one of the selects should also take effect to the other select element.

Is this possible?

**EDIT**

Tried to use $rootScope with $broadcast and $on. But when selecting a value from the first select field the second gets set to "empty" like nothing is selected. Selecting some value from the secong now results into an empty first selec field.

```
(function() {
'use strict';

var currencySelectionBox = function(ServiceFactory, $rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: false,
        template: '<select ng-options="o.currency_code for o in currencyList" ng-model="currencyListSelectedValue" class="form-control"></select>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            ServiceFactory.getCurrencies().then(function(response) {
                scope.currencyList = response.data.items;
            });

            element.bind("change", function(e) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('currencyChanged', scope.currencyListSelectedValue);
            });

            $rootScope.$on('currencyChanged', function(event, data) {
                scope.currencyListSelectedValue = data;
                console.log(scope.currencyListSelectedValue);

            });

        }
    };
};

angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('currencySelectionBox', ['ServiceFactory', '$rootScope', currencySelectionBox]);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

you can use `$rootScope` as a communication channel between directives. The directives will have most likely isolated scope and can not communicate with each other. So you use `$rootScope.$broadcast('eventName')` or `$rootScope.$emit('eventName')` to notify other directives of some event.

Then your directive listen with `$rootScope.$on('eventName', function(event, args){})`

You might want to set unique ID in each directive instance, and then broadcast this ID also, so that you can distinguish where the event is coming from.